# JavaScript: Trying to Create a Timer embedded on a webpage using jinja and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I am new to JS and Web Development, I am trying to develop a page that holds multiple timers for my job where these timers are going to be useful in helping our business. Here's the code.

```
class Timer {
    constructor(id) {
        console.log(id);
        this.value = document.getElementById("input-time"+id).value;
        this.time = value*60;
        this.timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000); 
    }
    async updaterTimer() {
        if(time == 0) clearInterval(timer);
        this.minutes = Math.floor( this.time/60);  
        let seconds =  time % 60;
        this.seconds = seconds<10 ? '0' + seconds: seconds;
        let timeElem = document.getElementById("time-"+id);
        timeElem.innerHTML = (minutes+":"+seconds);
        this.time--;    
    }
}
let timers = []
function timerHandler(id) {
    timers.append(new Timer(id));
}
```

HTML:

````
{% for group in user.groups %}
{% if group.active %}
<li class="list-group-item">
     Name: {{ group.full_name }}     Group ID: {{group.group_id }} 
      Phone Number: {{group.phone_number}}    Date: {{ group.time_started }}
            <div class="time" id="time-{{ group.group_id }}">00:00</div>
            <input type="text" id="input-time{{ group.group_id }}" name="input-time{{ group.group_id }}"> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="timerHandler({{ group.group_id }})">Enter</button>             
   {% endif %}
    <button type="button" class="close" onClick="unqeueGroup({{ group.group_id }})"
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</li>
{% endfor %}```

This code is not functional, and I am confused as to why. I am getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: timerHandler is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick " when I press the button, which I don't get because I defined timeHandler in that file. 

Please, all help is appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0):

The possible way of you get this problem is maybe the code is out of reach when the html is rendered an you can't have to the function anymore.
Check if you have access to the other variables in the scope using onLoad for example:

```
onLoad="console.log(Timer)"
```

If you don't get undefined, then try to copy/paste the name of the function.
But if it's undefined, then check the jinja documentation if you were missing something.